# MongoDB and Express - dynamic queries for routes with several id's

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

App is using Node and Express, and I have a MongoDB document with this structure, from `db.users.find().pretty()`:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("hash1"),
        "username" : "user1",
        "notes" : [
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("hash2"),
                        "data" : "This is note 1"
                }
        ],
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("hash3"),
        "username" : "user2",
        "notes" : [
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("hash4"),
                        "data" : "This is note 2"
                }
        ],
}
```

I need to remove a `notes` subdocument.

Using `findByIdAndUpdate` and `pull`, the route is:

```
app.delete('/users/:id/notes/:id', callback );
```

and the query:

```
var fieldsToSet = {
  $pull: {notes: {_id: req.params.id}}
};
var options = { new: true };
req.app.db.models.User
  .findByIdAndUpdate(req.user._id, fieldsToSet, options, callback)
```

I have no problem if I logged in as `user1` and want to delete a note with `hash2` ObjectId (see this as as a real hash generated by MongoDB), but if I still logged in as `user1` and I want to delete a note with `hash4` there is a problem, because I will always get a `user._id` with `hash1`. And i cant use `req.params.id` twice, it will always return me the last `:id` .
How can I get both id's dynamically?

Thanks

Comment: I am not able to understand your question properly but if you want to get multiple user id and dont want to use `req.params.id`, you can pass the param as an array of ids and fetch based on the condition.

Comment: The seemingly obvious solution is to rename each parameter so they are not the same `'/users/:userid/notes/:notesid'`. Beyond that I would presume ( untested ) that express was actually being smart about things and the content of `req.params.id` would actually be an "array". So therefore you "should" be able to access via the array index, i.e `req.params.id[0]` for the first index and using `1` for the second. But I really think the smart and clear thing to do here is simply name the parameters differently. There is nothing "making" you call them `id` if that was your misconception.

Comment: @Ajitej Kaushik I need to query dynamically twice - in finByIdAndUpdate - to find a user and in $pull to get the notes subdocument. I tried to use `req.params.id` both for user and the notes but it didnt work. Maybe I don do it right.

Comment: Then you will have to design you API and call it in such a fashion that it is called everytime a unqiue id is called. Can you please feed in some more code so that i can get a better insight.

Comment: @Neil Lunn your renaming solution works great! This should be an accepted answer. I tried your second solution but it didn't worked, probably bacause it is not the case of multiple objects, were talking here about a route which is a string. and not an array.

Comment: Like I said, "untested". it is however the usual case when parsing "form parameters" for instance where mutliple references to the same name result in an array. But it really is a lot cleaner to actually use separate naming when you need it. I actually interpreted your question as not understanding you could do that, and that you "thought" you were restricted to naming the parameters `id`. So really all I told you is "that is not the case".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have two different params for this, which makes sense since they're two things:

```
app.delete('/users/:userId/notes/:noteId', callback );
```

Then you can access the one you want with `req.params.nodeId` or `req.params.userId`